# Spring Security login doesn't work on amazon server

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, amazon-web-services, spring-security, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

my question is:

I configure with spring security a login page and it **works** great in **localhost** but when i deploy the .war in the **amazon elastic web service** (tomcat) no longer works.
When I insert the correct username and password spring always return me error and doesn't do the login, as if the data were wrong.
Doing research online I saw that it's probably a problem with https certificates.
Below the code:

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView login(HttpSession session, @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) boolean error) {

  ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();

  if (error) {
    model.addObject("error", "Wrong Data!");
    model.setViewName("Login");
    return model;   
  }

  model.setViewName("Login");
  return model;

}
```

login.jsp

```
        <form:form action="login" method="post">
                        <div align="center"><label>${error}</label></div>
                        &nbsp;                     
                        <div align="center"><label>User Name: </label><input type="text" name="username" /></div>  

                        <div align="center"><label>Password: </label><input type="password" name="password" /></div> 
                        &nbsp;
                        <div align="center"><input type="submit" class="button" value="Login" /></div>
            </form:form>
```

Security config

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)

    .usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT username,password,1 FROM user_model where username=?")
    .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT username,ruolo FROM user_model JOIN ruolo_model ON user_model.ruolo_id=ruolo_model.id where username=?");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login")
    .defaultSuccessUrl("/successLogin")
    .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
    .and()
    .csrf().disable();
    http.portMapper().http(80).mapsTo(443);
}
```

I add "http.portMapper().http(80).mapsTo(443)" for test but not work.

After login he always sends me to "/login?error=true".

Thanks to all!

Alessandro

Comment: Have you setup your IAM and put the credentials in the properties file?

Comment: My register page work so it's not a problem with credentials. What is IAM? Thank you!

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: Yes i found the problem. A very stupid problem. I forget to create a user role in db so spring security return me an error in the login process.